# Is it possible to solve for an input in python's RegularGridInterpolator?

Tags: scipy, interpolation, python-3.7

For an `engine`, `Thrust` is a function of `alpha, Mach, altitude` and `throttle` so I have

```
thrust_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((alpha, Mach, alt, throttle),
     thrust.reshape(len(alpha), len(Mach), len(alt), len(throttle)), 
     method='linear', bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)
```

I am wondering if I know my `thrust,alpha,Mach,alt;` can i 'reverse interpolate' to get the throttle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that works. thrust_req is the thrust you want, thrust_val is the output of the interpolation for a test throttle setting. x0 is the initial guess for the throttle setting. objective is to find the throttle setting that makes the interpolated thrust_val = thrust_req.

```
    def throttle_req(self, alpha, Mach, alt, thrust_req,x0):
    ''' Calculates steady flight at the given conditions
        Solves for altitude and throttle required
    '''
        def f(x,alpha,Mach,alt,thrust_req):
            throttle = x[0]
            thrust_val = self.ramjet_deck['thrust']((alpha,Mach,alt,throttle))
            return 10*(thrust_val-thrust_req)**2

    opt = minimize(f,x0, args=(alpha,Mach,alt,thrust_req), bounds=[(0.,1.)])
    throttle = opt.x[0]
    return throttle
```